# What is the correct way to parse variables using JavaParser?

Tags: java, javaparser

Using JavaParser I can get a list of my methods and fields using:

```
//List of all methods
System.out.println("Methods: " + this.toString());
List<TypeDeclaration> types = n.getTypes();
for (TypeDeclaration type : types)
{
    List<BodyDeclaration> members = type.getMembers();
    for (BodyDeclaration member : members)
    {
        if (member instanceof MethodDeclaration)
        {
            MethodDeclaration method = (MethodDeclaration) member;
            System.out.println("Methods: " + method.getName());
        }
    }
}

//List all field variables.
System.out.println("Field Variables: " + this.toString());
List<TypeDeclaration> f_vars = n.getTypes();
for (TypeDeclaration type : f_vars)
{
    List<BodyDeclaration> members = type.getMembers();
    for (BodyDeclaration member : members)
    {
        if (member instanceof FieldDeclaration)
        {
            FieldDeclaration myType = (FieldDeclaration) member;
            List <VariableDeclarator> myFields = myType.getVariables();
            System.out.println("Fields: " + myType.getType() + ":" + myFields.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get a list of my variables. I simply want a list of all variables from a java source, regardless of scope.

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question, don't edit it: feel free to answer it!

Comment: @Danilo Thanks for that I had no idea.

Comment: Just edit your question to remove the solution, and then paste it back as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to create a visitor class that extends VoidVisitorAdapter and override the visit() method. Code follows:

```
@Override
public void visit(VariableDeclarationExpr n, Object arg)
{      
    List <VariableDeclarator> myVars = n.getVars();
        for (VariableDeclarator vars: myVars){
            System.out.println("Variable Name: "+vars.getId().getName());
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that based on your solution, the original field listing can be done with the following code:

```
@Override
public void visit(FieldDeclaration n, Object arg) {
    System.out.println(n);
    super.visit(n, arg);
}
```

Don't forget to call super.visit, if you are overriding multiple visit methods in a visitor adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Working:

In the `visit(FieldDeclaration n, Object arg)` method of the `VoidVisitorAdapter` class, the following can be used for extracting variables.

It will give the exact name of the variables whether initialized or not.

```
String newstr;
List<VariableDeclarator> list = n.getVariables();
//as getVariables() returns a list we need to implement that way 
for (VariableDeclarator var : list) {

    String item = var.toString();

    if (item.contains("=")) {

        if (item != null && item.length() > 0) {

            int index = item.lastIndexOf("=");
            newstr = item.substring(0, index);
            newstr = newstr.trim();
            variablename = newstr;`
            //variablename is the name of the desired variable.
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pang for editing my answer. I'm new to this site and want to learn plus contribute.